# What system would I need if I want to store large amounts of text data and be able to control a TFT LCD display?

Tags: arduino, lcd, display

My goal is to build an electronics project where I can store large amounts of text data (books) where I want to display that text on a TFT-LCD display. Right now, I have my display hooked up to an Arduino Uno and I can display very little text (not enough memory to store more) and I would want to be able to display books (large amounts of text). I would need the project to be physically small. How would I go about doing something like that? Is there some type of PIC or an IC that can control a display and be able to store large amounts of text data as well?

Comment: Get an SD-card interface working.

Comment: Get a Kindle is my advice unless you are wanting to build something for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an microcontroller IC, a display, and a mass storage device. For your application, an SD card would be a good choice for the mass storage. Some microcontroller cards have an SD card slot built in. But if they don't, most microcontrollers have an appropriate interface. SD cards have several interface options, but for a microcontroller, the SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) is probably the best choice.